# How do I parse this string: a:10:{1:0;s:7:"default";i:1; ...?

Tags: php, database, deserialization

How can I read strings like that? What do they mean?

> `a:10:{i:0;s:7:"default";i:1;s:8:"failsafe";i:2;s:4:"foaf";i:3;s:4:"ical";i:4;s:2:"js";i:5;s:4:"json";i:6;s:6:"opendd";i:7;s:3:"php";i:8;s:3:"rss";i:9;s:3:"xml";}`

I've seen a lot of systems which use strings like that, stores it in the database and parse to get the values. How can I parse them?

Thanks.

Comment: its JSON. Basically it is name-value pairs

Comment: It is *not* JSON.  Not not not not not not not not not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a serialized string.  Look at the results of `var_dump(unserialize())`.  It is NOT a valid JSON-formatted string (`json_decode()` will return null).

If you want to actually "read" it without unserializing it, you can see `"a:10"` means array with 10 indices. `"i:0"` means "index zero" and is semicolon-separated with the corresponding value (`"s:7"` is a string of length 7). The values are comma separated. Classes can also be serialized.

Comment: Great answer with a great explanation!

Comment: Thanks. The unserialize() function only unserialize one variable at once?

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. I was just checking. Later I'll read more about that and useful ways to work with. Thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

It's not JSON, it is a serialized array. Use `unserialize()` to turn it into something usable.