# string / array format convert with php

Tags: php, wordpress

i'm manually reading out database entries from a plugin (eventscalendar wordpress). there are user defined fields / custom fields stored in the database. excuse my ignorance - but i'm having trouble associating the format the data is stored in:

```
a:1:{s:3:"key";s:6:"extern";}
```

so in the end all i would need is the value of s:6:"" in a simple variable.
lets say $key = "extern"

any quick solutions?
thanks,
mark

Comment: It's PHPs [`serialize`](http://php.net/serialize) format, which your PHP code could decode again to get the individual entries.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I parse this string: a:10:{1:0;s:7:"default";i:1; ...?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997660/how-do-i-parse-this-string-a1010s7defaulti1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at unserialize to get it back into an array: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Answer (score 1):

That is a serialized array-- note the `a` at the beginning. It also works on Objects.

It is created with PHP's [`serialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and converted back to proper array/object with [`unserialize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).

It serves a similar purpose to the [`JSON`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format.